# How can I add a column with specific values and calculate the percentage?

Tags: sql, r, oracle, percentage

I have received from a **select** query this kind of table (just a simple example):

```
D         C         Letter
20153     200       x
20154     300       x
20161     250       x
20162     180       x
20153     500       y
20154     380       y
20161     550       y
20162     170       y
20153     230       z
20154     700       z
20161     210       z
20162     185       z
```

So, the column D repeats after four entries. C is always different and Letter changes after four entries.
In total, 20153 has 100.000, 20154 has 150.000, 20161 has 300.000 and 20162 has 250.000 entries. I would like to put these values to the corresponding numbers, calculate the percentage so it looks like this:

```
D         C         Letter    Total      Perc
20153     200       x         100.000    0.002
20154     300       x         150.000    0.002
20161     250       x         300.000    0.008
20162     180       x         250.000    ...
20153     500       y         100.000    ...
20154     380       y         150.000    ...
20161     550       y         300.000    ...
20162     170       y         250.000    ...
20153     230       z         100.000    ...
20154     700       z         150.000    ...
20161     210       z         300.000    ... 
20162     185       z         250.000    ...
```

How can I do this?
Provided solutions can also be written in R.

Comment: SO is not a *write code for me* service. please show your attempt so far.

Comment: Please add a tag for database (Oracle / PostgreSQL / SQL Server / MySQL etc.) + version

Comment: Well, I tried it with cbind until the end of my df (1:nrow(df)) but somehow it gives me an error. Probably because I have four different values instead of just one for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define somewhere Your given vectors, for example in subquery `V`. Subquery `X` adds column `RN` with rows partitioned by `letter` and ordered by `D`. Now we can `join` these two queries and make division:

```
with 
  v as (select 1 rn, 100000 as total from dual union all
        select 2 rn, 150000 as total from dual union all
        select 3 rn, 300000 as total from dual union all
        select 4 rn, 250000 as total from dual ),
  x as (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by letter order by d) rn
          from t)
select rn, d, c, letter, total, cast(c / total as number(8, 5)) percent
  from x join v using (rn)
  order by letter, d
```

Test data and output:

```
create table t (d number(6), c number(6), letter varchar2(2));
insert into t values (20153, 200, 'x');
insert into t values (20154, 300, 'x');
insert into t values (20161, 250, 'x');
insert into t values (20162, 180, 'x');
insert into t values (20153, 500, 'y');
insert into t values (20154, 380, 'y');
insert into t values (20161, 550, 'y');
insert into t values (20162, 170, 'y');
insert into t values (20153, 230, 'z');
insert into t values (20154, 700, 'z');
insert into t values (20161, 210, 'z');
insert into t values (20162, 185, 'z');


    RN       D       C LETTER      TOTAL    PERCENT
 ----- ------- ------- ------ ---------- ----------
     1   20153     200 x          100000    0,00200
     2   20154     300 x          150000    0,00200
     3   20161     250 x          300000    0,00083
     4   20162     180 x          250000    0,00072
     1   20153     500 y          100000    0,00500
     2   20154     380 y          150000    0,00253
     3   20161     550 y          300000    0,00183
     4   20162     170 y          250000    0,00068
     1   20153     230 z          100000    0,00230
     2   20154     700 z          150000    0,00467
     3   20161     210 z          300000    0,00070
     4   20162     185 z          250000    0,00074
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on some databases

```
select      D,C,Letter
           ,sum(C) over (partition by D)            as Total
           ,C / sum(C) over (partition by D) * 100  as Perc

from        mytable
```

If it doesn't work on your database then try the following

```
select      t.D,t.C,t.Letter
           ,s.Total
           ,t.C / c.Total * 100  as Perc

from        mytable t

            join (select      D,sum(C) as Total 
                  from        mytable
                  group by    D
                  ) s 

            on    s.D = t.D
```

Comment: I had already tried this one, but it gives me the wrong sum. My example is just an extract from my table, which means there are many more rows.

Comment: How does your first comment relates to this solution?

Comment: If you count all 20153 together, you get 930 and not 100.000. Total is a given vector, which is repeating after every four entries. I do not know how to bind a given and repeating vector to a table. Instead I fixed this in R.

Comment: (1) 100.000 = 100K?  (2) I didn't count, I summed. (3) There isn't "every four entries" because there is no order in a data set and no column in your sample that you can use to order by. (4) The order doesn't really matter if the grouping is defined by D